'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'tz'
I am attempting to prep some data to work with the AlphaLens library. I am following the code included in a textbook published from 2020 but some of the libraries and methods are not current so I need to make modifications along the way. I have been struggling with this error all morning and am stuck as to how to make sure that my DateTime indices are aligned. Can anyone suggest some potential tests?
Here is the code I am trying to run:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

%matplotlib inline
import re
from alphalens.utils import get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns
from alphalens.performance import *
from alphalens.plotting import *
from alphalens.tears import *

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
# This is referring to data from another file that already works correctly
performance = pd.read_pickle('single_factor.pickle')

prices = pd.concat([df.to_frame(d) for d, df in performance.prices.dropna().items()],axis=1).T
prices.columns = [re.findall(r"\[(.+)\]", str(col))[0] for col in prices.columns]
prices.index = prices.index.normalize()
prices.index = prices.index.tz_convert('UTC')
prices.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col, '') for col in prices.columns])
prices = prices.stack(0)

factor_data = pd.concat([df.to_frame(d) for d, df in performance.factor_data.dropna().items()],axis=1).T
factor_data.columns = [re.findall(r"\[(.+)\]", str(col))[0] for col in factor_data.columns]
factor_data.index = factor_data.index.normalize()
factor_data.index = factor_data.index.tz_convert('UTC')
factor_data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col, '') for col in factor_data.columns])
factor_data = factor_data.stack(0)
factor_data.index.names = ['date', 'asset']
prices.index.names = ['date', 'asset']

with pd.HDFStore('PATH/assets.h5') as store:
    sp500 = store['sp500/stooq'].close
sp500 = sp500.resample('D').ffill().tz_localize('utc').filter(prices.index.get_level_values(0))

factor_data.index = factor_data.index.set_levels([factor_data.index.levels[0].tz_convert('UTC')], level=['date'])
prices.index = prices.index.set_levels([prices.index.levels[0].tz_convert('UTC')], level=['date'])

HOLDING_PERIODS = (5, 10, 21, 42)
QUANTILES = 5

# Ensure factor_data is a DataFrame with a MultiIndex
assert isinstance(factor_data, pd.DataFrame)
assert isinstance(factor_data.index, pd.MultiIndex)

# Ensure prices is a DataFrame
assert isinstance(prices, pd.DataFrame)

# Ensure HOLDING_PERIODS is a tuple
assert isinstance(HOLDING_PERIODS, tuple)

# Ensure QUANTILES is an integer
assert isinstance(QUANTILES, int)

alphalens_data = get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(factor=factor_data,
                                                      prices=prices,
                                                      periods=HOLDING_PERIODS,
                                                      quantiles=QUANTILES)

I keep receiving the following error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 1
----> 1 alphalens_data = get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(factor=factor_data,
      2                                                       prices=prices,
      3                                                       periods=HOLDING_PERIODS,
      4                                                       quantiles=QUANTILES)

File ~/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alphalens/utils.py:827, in get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(factor, prices, groupby, binning_by_group, quantiles, bins, periods, filter_zscore, groupby_labels, max_loss, zero_aware, cumulative_returns)
    666 def get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(factor,
    667                                          prices,
    668                                          groupby=None,
   (...)
    676                                          zero_aware=False,
    677                                          cumulative_returns=True):
    678     """
    679     Formats the factor data, pricing data, and group mappings into a DataFrame
    680     that contains aligned MultiIndex indices of timestamp and asset. The
   (...)
    825         For use when forward returns are already available.
    826     """
--> 827     forward_returns = compute_forward_returns(
    828         factor,
    829         prices,
    830         periods,
...
    266                                    "the pandas methods tz_localize and "
    267                                    "tz_convert.")
    269 freq = infer_trading_calendar(factor_dateindex, prices.index)

AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'tz'

I have tried multiple times to validate that the timezone data is compatible, which is appears to be. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.
EDIT:I can inspect the changes to the 'prices' and 'factor_data' dataframes by running one line at a time and viewing the changes in VSCode Data Viewer. I have attached screenshots for those changes.
Timezone format after running prices.index = prices.index.normalize()

Timezone format after running prices.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col, '') for col in prices.columns])

Timezone format after running prices = prices.stack(0)


based on the error message, the error is caused in get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns, not in the code you show. Note: just like an index, a multi-index has no tz namespace.

Thanks @FObersteiner, I am running this is VSCode IDE extension from GitHub repo. I can inspect both the 'prices' and 'factor_data' dataframes to verify the timezone formats after formatting the dataframes as requested.

thanks for updating; looks like your index is just string, not datetime, is that correct?

I don't think so. If I run
print(type(prices.index.get_level_values('date')[0]))
I receive the following output.
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

I ended up just adding a line for start and end as follows.
start = start.tz_convert(None)
end = end.tz_convert(None)

I used 'None' as the key because that was the default method, for some reason using 'UTC' set off another series of errors and I realized that the default was 'UTC' anyways so that seemed to fix the issue.
